# Rails Create method Validation Error with one to one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have been learning ruby on rails from Coursera and am specifically at the one to one to one association module. I was trying to emulate the one to one association example in the tutorial on my own system however i get the ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid error. This is what i have done to reach this point:

1) rails g model person first_name last_name
2) rake db:migrate
3) rails g model personal_info height:float weight:float person references
4) rake db:migrate
5) Migration 20160725143537_create_people.rb has the following code:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
   create_table :people do |t|
    t.string :first_name
    t.integer :age
    t.string :last_name
    t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

6) Migration 20160727184247_create_personal_infos.rb has the following code:-

```
class CreatePersonalInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :personal_infos do |t|
      t.float :height
      t.float :weight
      t.references :person, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
   end
end
```

end

7) The code in person.rb is as follows:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :personal_info
end
```

8) The code in personal_info.rb is as follows:-

```
class PersonalInfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
end
```

9) The code in seeds.rb is as follows:-

```
Person.destroy_all

Person.create! [
{first_name: "Kalman", last_name: "Smith", age: 33, login: "kman", pass: "abc123"},
{first_name: "John", last_name: "Whatever", age: 27, login: "john1", pass: "123abc"},
{first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Smith", age: 15, login: "mike", pass: "not_telling"},
{first_name: "Josh", last_name: "Oreck", age: 57, login: "josh", pass: "password1"},
{first_name: "John", last_name: "Smith", age: 27, login: "john2", pass: "no_idea"},
{first_name: "Bill", last_name: "Gates", age: 75, login: "bill", pass: "windows3.1"},
{first_name: "LeBron", last_name: "James", age: 30, login: "bron", pass: "need more rings"},]
```

10) Now i go to the rails console (rails c) and type the following:
pi1 = PersonalInfo.create!(height:6.2, weight:220.0). This is when i get the aforementioned error which looks like this:

irb(main):002:0> pi1 = PersonalInfo.create!(height:6.2, weight:220.0)

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Person must exist
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `block in save!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `save!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:45:in `save!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
    from (irb):2
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'irb(main):003:0>
```

I am using rails 5. 
I would really appreciate you guys helping me in resolving this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set a `person_id`:

```
PersonalInfo.create!(person_id: 1, height:6.2, weight:220.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you have defined `has_one` association between `Person` and `PersonalInfo`.
The best way to create `PersonalInfo` first you should create `Person` then `PersonalInfo` such as:

```
@person = Person.create!(first_name: "Kalman", last_name: "Smith", age: 33, login: "kman", pass: "abc123")
```

Now you can create PersonalInfo

```
@person.personal_info.create(height:6.2, weight:220.0)
```

I think it would help you. Still if you have any concern please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. So in the coursera video tutorial, the example that they were showing, in that they were initially setting nil foreign key values for a record and then setting that record directly on the table there was an association with. So for eg,
    
person1 = Person.find_by!(first_name:"BIll")    
pi1 = PersonalInfo.create(height:6.2, weight:220.0)
person1.personal_info = pi1

Comment: This is what i was trying to do just to emulate the example shown in the tutorial but turn out that in rails 5 in order to have nil foreign key values we need to add optional:true next to the belongs_to statement in the appropriate class. This is what i ended up doing although you are right because it makes more sense to just adhere to the foreign key constraint and create the parent class record first and then create its reference in the child class record. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your `CreatePersonalInfos` migration, the `person` reference has a foreign key constraint. This means you won't be able to create `PersonalInfo` without an associated `Person`. You can either create it by providing a valid `person_id`

```
PersonalInfo.create!(height:6.2, weight:220.0, person_id:1)
```

or through the association on Person

```
@person.create_personal_info(height:6.2, weight:220.0)
```

You can also remove the `foreign_key` option in your migration to remove the DB-level constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your help!